# Cannot install Subversive connectors in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I am trying to install Subversive SVN connectors but I keep getting this horrible error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Subversive SVN Connectors 2.3.0.I20120520-1700 (org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.feature.group 2.3.0.I20120520-1700)
  Missing requirement: Subversive SVN Connectors 2.3.0.I20120520-1700 (org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.feature.group 2.3.0.I20120520-1700) requires 'org.eclipse.team.svn.feature.group [0.7.9.I20120413-1700,1.0.0)' but it could not be found
```

I have Kepler version of Eclipse and am trying to connect to an SVN repository.

What do I need to install in order for this to work.

[image]

Comment: Before the connector, have you installed the subversive plugin?

Comment: @robermann What's the name of it?

Comment: ... Subversive :) For more information: https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/

Comment: Yes I have the subversive plugin

Comment: heya @RymanHolmes have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have a mixed experience when installing things in Eclipse with these methods:

- **Help | Install software...**
- **Help | Eclipse Marketplace**

They don't work the same way. For some things one works out of the box, for other things it's the other.

I remember I recently installed Subversive in a fresh new Kepler, using the marketplace method and it worked flawlessly. Right now I tried it in Debian at home, and again it worked flawlessly. There are two steps, actually. After installing Subversive from marketplace, + restart, when I try to add a repository URL it asks to install the connector, + restart.

This worked well for me with a clean new Kepler in two different operating systems.